# CSS: Convert vertical menu to horizontal

Tags: html, css, menu

How to convert the vertical menu into horizontal? Which lines in the below-given code are responsible for this?

```
ul#vertmenu {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
ul#vertmenu li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    font: bold 11px/16px arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
ul#vertmenu li ul li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFCF8B;
}
ul#vertmenu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 3px;
}
ul#vertmenu li a:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFCF8B;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    color: #AA0000;
}
ul#vertmenu li ul li a:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFEDD3;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
ul#vertmenu ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
ul#vertmenu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    left: 200px;
}
```

I found the answer [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-30960.html). Exactly what I wanted to know:

"First, take out all the mentions of a "width". You're going to want your menu to span your page not be restricted to the 180px in the current version.

Next, we need to tell the

elements to lay in-line with each other, instead of stack top to bottom. So, add display:inline to #vertmenu li.

After that, we'll need to tell the elements to follow suit. So, remove display:block from the #vertmenu li a decleration. "

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question could be improved by showing the relevant HTML, and by making a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your menu.

Comment: posting your html will be helpful

Comment: HTML is very classical: <ul id ="vertmenu"><li>123</li><li>456</li></ul>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change `display:block;` to

```
  display:inline;
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed,but my menu still looks the same - i.e. vertical.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding

```
li
{
display:inline;
}
```

also in your code

```
 ul#vertmenu li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    font: bold 11px/16px arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here you setting the `li` to `ul` width. Remove that.

Simple [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly8Um/3/)

Answer (score 0):

**Change** the style of your list to  ( for eg: unordered), You can style with the class or id of that list too.

```
ul{
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-x: auto;  
    }
```

And change the **style of li** to be an **inline-block**

```
li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li {
  display: inline;
}
```

and not the whole thing into display:inline
try isolate.